# How to unmount component before redirecting to external url?

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Note` component where a user edits a Note. Now, in my header for the app I have a button which can be clicked and you will be sent to the base product of the company - which is an external URL.

My problem is that the `componentWillUnmount` function (yes, this is the "old" component based API used in this particular component) does not fire and so any unsaved changes disappear.

Ideas?

I've tried adding an event listener in `componentDidMount`
`window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.componentWillUnmount);` but my request is still getting cancelled before the redirect. I'm using apollo with graphql endpoints btw.

Comment: Where is the Note being saved, a database?

Comment: Yes, a database. I've added an update btw!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how rewriting to hooks can help here.
Looks like the problem is that you, actually, do not unmount component, but leave the page. React will never know about this event.

I think, you can use another approach to keep changes: send it to the backend while user filling the note. Or, maybe, easiest way is to duplicate changes in localStorage and then recover it on new load. But it feels less secure and, of course, limited by this browser/machine

Comment: Makes sense, although I do send to backend every two minutes but I have to release editing too which is the call I do in the unmounting stage. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas you could try:

1. When the user clicks the button in the header, run a function/method to save the Note before redirecting.
2. Add an onblur listener to Note and trigger a function/method to save when Note input field loses focus
3. Add an onkeypress listener and save the contents of Note with every keypress (or every x seconds to batch the updates instead).